# How to condense a melted wax in to small aggregate forms like stones of different sizes?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am an Architect trying to do some experiments with wax. Normally when the wax is melted and poured on to a surface and it takes the shape of the surface with some strings formed . But instead I would like to condense the wax before it hits the surface so it becomes a small aggregate of varying sizes in the form of a stone . How can this be achieved ?

I want it to condense quickly before it hits the surface once its relieved from the melting point and gets in contact with the room temperature of 12-14 Degrees celcius.Should any solvent be added to the melted wax to achieve this state I wanted?

Your suggestions are most welcomed.

Comment: Pour it into the water.

Comment: large-scale version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_tower

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that wax is an amorphous solid and a mixture of various compounds.  This causes it to have no specific temperature that can be defined as a melting point, but rather a range of temperatures where it transforms from a hard brittle solid to a soft plyable solid to a liquid. 
The best I can recomend is that you first pour very hot wax into a much larger amount of ice cold water to form wax shot.  Then take the shot and a propane torch, torch the wax beads as they fall to partially melt the surface of the shot and that may get you your desired effect.